# How to use Firefox dev tool profiler on chrome?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, profiler

I'm trying to use Firefox dev tools to profile what happens in the australis customize area when I add a widget to a toolbar and when I add it to the panel.

But I can't figure out how to get the profiler to work. Press Ctrl+Shift+k while in the customize tab won't even bring it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the "Browser Toolbox" from the Developer menu.

If you don't see it, just go to any normal web page, bring up the ctrl-shift-k console, click on the settings cog on the top left and then enable the advanced option called "enable chrome debugging".

Comment: Oh fantastic!! Thanks very much! Its really slowing down my computer though :(

Comment: Ah I just closed some tabs and restarted the browser toolbox and its working good thanks man so much!